# Is the Seriate module for Node secure?

Tags: node.js

For my project I have about 5 modules, 1 of which (seriate) returns the following message when I install it.

```
found 17 vulnerabilities (9 low, 8 moderate)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

This has given me cause for concern, my project handles data that I want to be as secure as possible.

I have an `npm audit fix`and it fails to run.

Any advice on how what I should do is massively appreciated, also if anyone can share their experience of Seriate I would be grateful.

Also: I need 1500 rep to tag `node-seriate`, could someone help me with that too? Thanks!

Comment: As far as i can tell seriate itself is not the problem but its dependencies. There is a lot of dependency in seriate and their dependencies are not up to date. So you might fix your dependencies by issuing this command depending to package depth `npm update lodash --depth 4` it's just a sample you need you review your dependencies on your own there is no easy fix here.

Comment: @metoikos ok thanks for this! Is it possible that the dependency issues could create a security issue?

Comment: Of course it could! That's the problem